# How to configure TestNG Reporter parameter in Gradle task

Tags: testng, gradle

I am executing TestNG tests via Gradle. I want to configure the value of stackTraceOutputMethod for the default XMLReporter.

This is my Gradle task

```
// runs test cases using TestNG framework
task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
   main = 'org.testng.TestNG'
   args '-reporter org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter:stackTraceOutputMethod="0" testng.xml'
   classpath configurations.runtime
   systemProperties 'logDir': 'logs'
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
15:30:36.343 [ERROR] [system.err] Unknown option: -reporter org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter:stackTraceOutputMethod=0 testng.xml
15:30:36.390 [QUIET] [system.out] Usage:  [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -configfailurepolicy               Configuration failure policy (skip or
                                       continue)
    -d                                 Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount           Number of threads to use when running
                                       data providers
    -excludegroups                     Comma-separated list of group names to
                                       exclude
.
.
.
```

I guess the way I am providing the Java args is incorrect.

```
args '-reporter org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter:stackTraceOutputMethod="0" testng.xml'
```

Can somebody let me know what is the correct way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of passing multiple args is:

```
args '-reporter','....','testng.xml'
```

So each argument goes in its own string. Instead of passing them all space-separated.

**Update**

TestNG is actually pretty easy to configure in Gradle, I'd suggest you use the following:

```
task runTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    options {
        listeners << '...'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried <br />args '-reporter' 'org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter', 'stackTraceOutputMethod=0', 'testng.xml'<br /><br /> Am getting the following error:<br /> Build failed with an exception.
<br /> startup failed:
<br />build file 'D:\R43_playit\demoProject\build.gradle': 23: expecting '}', found ','
 @ line 23, column 56.

Comment: Could you post your updated gradle build file, you've got a syntax error somewhere then...

Comment: // runs test cases using TestNG framework
task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main = 'org.testng.TestNG'
    args 'testng.xml'
    classpath configurations.runtime
    systemProperties 'logDir': 'logs'
}

Comment: aneez, can you use formatting, that makes it easier to read, and what is on line 22 and 23?

Comment: `// runs test cases using TestNG framework   
task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {   
 main = 'org.testng.TestNG'   
 args 'testng.xml'   
 classpath configurations.runtime   
 systemProperties 'logDir': 'logs'   
}`

Comment: Hiery, am not sure if we can format code in comments. On line 22, I am making a call to the main class of TestNG (its a testing framework). On line 22 am passing command line arguments to it. You can check details about the arguments I am trying to pass here: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html (search for the text: stackTraceOutputMethod)

Comment: "task runTests(type: Test) ...." doesn't work in my use case as I am using some custom plugins. Hence, am using the JavaExec feature.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle in a gist (at gist.github.com)?